# Creating a shifted & scaled Beta in pymc3

Tags: python, scipy, pymc3

I'm trying to create a beta RV that behaves like the one in [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.beta.html). Namely, it takes an `alpha`, `beta`, `loc`, and `scale`. I followed the discussion on creating a [shifted gamma](https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/issues/864#issuecomment-285864556), and came up with something that looks like this:

```
import pymc3 as pm

class SSBeta(pm.Beta):
    def __init__(self, alpha, beta, loc, scale, *args, **kwargs):

        # Not sure what this is doing but it won't work without it. 
        transform = pm.distributions.transforms.lowerbound(loc)

        super().__init__(alpha=alpha, beta=beta, *args, **kwargs, transform=transform)

        self.scale = scale
        self.loc = loc
        self.mean += loc

    def random(self):
        return super().random()*self.scale + self.loc

    def logp(self, x):
        return super().logp((x - self.loc)/self.scale)
```

So I have two questions:

- Is this implementation correct (`random`, `logp`)?
- What's the purpose of the transform at the top of the class? I can't find anything useful in the docs and the code didn't help a ton.

Comment: That implementation looks fine to me - you should not need a transform (which sometimes makes sampling easier - for example, allowing you to sample from all the reals instead of just the positives).  Is something going wrong with it?  I have posted an alternative as an answer.

Comment: When calling it with price = SSBeta("price", 2, 5, 20, 10) I get "ValueError: Bad initial energy: nan. The model might be misspecified." when I remove that transform line. (Using: joblib-0.11 pymc3-3.3 theano-1.0.1 tqdm-4.19.5)

Comment: Oh interesting - yes, `Beta` uses the `logodds` transform, which assumes all proposals will be in [0, 1] (and so throws the error, because price must be between 20 and 30 in your example).  I would use instead `transform = pm.distributions.transforms.interval(loc, loc + scale)`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is using `pm.Deterministic`.  This does not allow you to pass observed data, but might be what you want anyways?

```
mu, scale = 2, 4
with pm.Model():
    b = pm.Beta('b', alpha=3, beta=8)
    shifted_b = pm.Deterministic('shifted_b', scale * b + mu)
```

[image]

Comment: That's an interesting idea but, yes, not being able to pass observed data would be limiting. (Reference: https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/issues/1971)